# How is TINYINT(1) converted to BOOL/BOOLEAN?

Tags: mysql, datatypes

I can understand that if you UPDATE a `TINYINT(1)` column and pass a value of *1* or *0* it will convert it to *TRUE* or *FALSE*, respectively.

I'm just confused on what happens when you UPDATE the column with a different value, say *2*. In other words, if you UPDATE a `TINYINT(1)` column with the value *2*, will this be *TRUE* or *FALSE*? Or, is this even doable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A tinyint column can hold values from 0 to 255 (if it is defined as `unsigned`) or -128 to +127 (if it is `signed`). The `(1)` in `tinyint(1)` is only for some formatting options and generally ignored. You could create it as `tinyint(100)` and it wouldn't make a difference.

Regarding the `TRUE` or `FALSE`, any int (int, tinyint, smallint, bigint) value can be used as (or converted to) a boolean value. It is considered `FALSE` if it is `0` and `TRUE` otherwise. So, `2` would count as `TRUE`.

To be entirely clear, MySQL does not have a true `BOOLEAN` type. `BOOLEAN` is a synonym of `TINYINT(1)`, as the docs explain in [Numeric Type Overview](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html):

> `BOOL`, `BOOLEAN`
>
> These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. **A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true**:
>
> ...
>
> However, **the values `TRUE` and `FALSE` are merely aliases for 1 and 0**, respectively, as shown here:
>
> ...

Comment: ¿so it could make sense to create a boolean with a check like `is_true boolean NOT NULL CHECK(is_true IN(TRUE, FALSE))` right?

Comment: @CanRau indeed, to be safe against any application that tries to insert 2 or 3 or 17 into such a column or cannot handle properly such ill values. And assuming that you are on a recent enough version of MySQL that has implemented CHECK constraints (old versions do not).

Comment: Thanks for confirming  yes I'm on MySQL 8 (Planetscale) good to know about the compatibility requirement

Comment: Just wanted to add to my question if I should also mark it as `boolean UNSIGNED`, if that would help with anything, but then found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74376677/3484824 so it seems better to be avoided as `bool`/`boolean` are synonyms of `tinyint(1)` and not `tinyint(1) UNSIGNED` and libraries and ORMs might depend on this